# (Amateur) data manipulation in R: variable levels as new column with its values from another column

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I would like to create a new column which extracts 'b' and 'c' from `type` and puts the `value` in that column. There are other random columns in between as well that should be kept which I just named `random`.

```
id <- c("1", "1", "1", "1","2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3")
type <- c("a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", "c")
random <- c("random")
value <- c("1", "2", "50", "100", "4", "5", "55", "110", "2.5", "3", "53", "105")

df <- data.frame(id, type, random, value)

  id type random value
1   1    a random     1
2   1    a random     2
3   1    b random    50
4   1    c random   100
5   2    a random     4
6   2    a random     5
7   2    b random    55
8   2    c random   110
9   3    a random   2.5
10  3    a random     3
11  3    b random    53
12  3    c random   105
```

What I would like to have is:

```
  id2 type2 random value2  b   c
1   1     a random      1 50 100
2   1     a random      2 50 100
3   2     a random      4 55 110
4   2     a random      5 55 110
5   3     a random    2.5 53 105
6   3     a random      3 53 105
```

Would very much appreciate some thoughts! Best,

Comment: Can you show a more general example with more 'id

Comment: hi @akrun, thank you for your help already, you're the best!!! I have edited the post and I think it is more clear now. could you please confirm this?

Comment: @Mark-Marijn Let's say the second value of 'id' is type' 'b', and its value is 85.  then what would be the expected output i.e. instead of value = 5, it is value = 85

Comment: @Mark-Marjin can you pllease check my updated solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could group by 'id', create the 'b' column by extracting the 'value' where the 'type' is 'b' (assuming single value of 'b' per group), `ungroup` and remove the row where 'type' is 'b'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(b = value[type == 'b']) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    filter(type != 'b')
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  id    type  keepthis value b    
#  <fct> <fct> <fct>    <fct> <fct>
#1 1     a     keep     4     95   
#2 1     a     keep     5     95   
#3 2     a     keep     3     94   
#4 2     a     keep     5     94
```

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset, we could `filter` the 'type' with 'b', 'c', do a reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`, `left_join` with the original dataset `filter`ed with only 'type' 'a'

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
     filter(type %in% c('b', 'c'))  %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = value) %>%
     left_join(df %>% 
             filter(type  == 'a'))
# A tibble: 6 x 6
#  id    random b     c     type  value
#* <fct> <fct>  <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
#1 1     random 50    100   a     1    
#2 1     random 50    100   a     2    
#3 2     random 55    110   a     4    
#4 2     random 55    110   a     5    
#5 3     random 53    105   a     2.5  
#6 3     random 53    105   a     3
```

With updated dataset, the code would be

```
df %>%
    filter(scale_id %in% c('IM', 'RT')) %>% 
    select(Title, Task, task_id, scale_id, data_value) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = scale_id, values_from  = data_value) %>% 
    left_join(df %>% 
                  filter(! scale_id %in% c('IM', 'RT')) %>% 
                  group_by(task_id) %>%
                  slice(which.max(data_value)))
```

Comment: thank you! I get an error at line `mutate(b = value[type == 'b']) %>%`. Namely, it says: Error: Column `importance` must be length 45 (the group size) or one, not 5.
This is my actual code now: `dfTaskRatingsTMP %>%
  group_by(task_id) %>%
  mutate(importance = data_value[scale_id == 'IM']) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  filter(type != 'IM')`

Comment: @Marc-Marijn I. assumed that you have only a single element of 'b' per each 'id' based on the example

Comment: @Marc-Marijn can you please update your post with a case where there are multiple 'b' value for each 'id' and in that casee, what would be selected

Comment: Oh sorry! Per 'id' (of which there are many) there are multiple 'a' values and one 'b' value.

Comment: @Marc-Marijn can you try `df %>% filter(type == 'b') %>% mutate(type = 'a') %>% rename(b = value) %>% bind_rows(df %>% filter(type != 'b'), .) %>% group_by(id) %>% fill(b, .direction = 'updown') %>% ungroup %>% filter(!is.na(value))`

Comment: @Marc-Marijn can you please update with that case because I wanted to know which values would be selected because it will cause an issue with length

Comment: @Marc-Marijn it would be better if you make all those changes in a more general case and its expected output because from my side, not able to undersstand the expected output

Comment: hi @akrun, I changes the question and I believe it is more clear now. thanks a million for your help again, could you please confirm if this is clear? also, can I donate a small amount to you somewhere...?

Comment: @Marc-Marijn can you please check if the updated solutioin works

Comment: When I run the code, `value` and `scale_id` only have 'NA' values.  However, I would need them in their original state but simply without 'a' and 'b'. Would that be possible? Again, can I donate to you somewhere? Happy to do!

Comment: @Marc-Marijn NOt clear about your case.  is it possible to send a bigger example via email alongg wth some expected output. It's okay.  It's all free help

Comment: Wow, that is so amazing you, extremely kind!!! Yes I will provide you the example asap; what is the e-mail address I can reach you on?

Comment: I don't understand, where could I have gotten your e-mail?